# .ttf files are not served to CSS from JSP

Tags: eclipse, jsp, tomcat

I created a Dynamic Web Project in Eclipse and wanted to use some font faces in the JSP files. I added a `.css` file to the project in Eclipse and  put the following code in the file:

```
@font-face{
font-family: "Font Name";
src: url("FontName.ttf") format("truetype");
}
```

I put the `FontName.ttf` file manually (NOT by adding it using Eclipse) in the `WebContent` folder. `.css` file also lies in the same folder.

**Problem:**

I am using Tomcat server and whenever the browser requests this file, server responds with `404 Resource Not Found` . Why does this occur?

**Checks done:**

The `web.xml` in of Tomcat contains appropriate mime types to handle the `.ttf` files. Specifically, these lines are present in this file:

```
  <mime-mapping>
     <extension>ttf</extension>
      <mime-type>application/x-font-ttf</mime-type>
  </mime-mapping>
```

2. I also put the `FontName.ttf` file in the main project directory. That was also not working.
3. I had thought that the problem was caused because of not adding the `.ttf` through Eclipse? If this is indeed the case, how can I add this file to the project using Eclipse? I could not find an appropriate way.

Comment: Eclipse sometimes (or always?) doesn't notice when you add or change files externally. Try right clicking your project and select Refresh from menu (or hit F5), that usually helps. Btw: you can copy and paste the file into Eclipse (just select the file in your file explorer, hit CTRL+C, select location in Eclipse's project explorer and hit CTRL+v) or you can even drag and drop it

Comment: I did this. The `.ttf` file was added under JAX-WS Web Services. But this didn't work :(